# SQLALCHEMY: getting row ID from value inside key/value pair

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, key-value

I've got to access a pretty messy postgresql database. The one table has three columns:

```
PK [PK]Bigint| a_key [PK] text[] | a_val text[]
1, {name, job, age}, {'John', 'Eng', '31'}
2, {job, ID}, {'IT', '1234'}
3, {ID, age, name, BFF}, {'4321', '22', 'Piet', 'John'}
```

I'm trying to use some sqlalchemy in python to find the primary key of a row based on a value inside key/value pair:

```
RETURN PK where name == 'John'
```

I've can get all the rows that have a "name" entry and then do a loop in python to find "John":

```
obj = session.query(table).filter(table.c.a_key.any(u'name')).all()
```

but I would rather have the database figure it all out and just return the 'PK'.  Any ideas?

Comment: if those columns are of type array, you should unnest em and compare two columns

Comment: `{'John', 'Eng', '31'}` is neither text[], nor JSON - it's just a text - right?..

Comment: PGadmin says that they're text[]

Comment: then data is populated wrong I guess - `a_val[1]` is not `John`, but `'John'`... anyway - you can use unnest, I posted sample in answer

Comment: I inherited this mess from someone else who didn't believe in commenting code and that variable names are a scarce resource and should be reused as much as possible... There's lots wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast columns as arrays, you can query `unnest`, like here:

```
t=# create table so28 (pk int,a_key text[],a_val int[]);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so28 select ^C
t=# create table so29 (pk int,a_key text[],a_val text[]);                                                                          CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so29 select 1,'{name, job, age}', $${'John', 'Eng', '31'}$$;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so29 select 2,'{job, ID}', $${'IT', '1234'}$$;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so29 select 3, '{ID, age, name, BFF}', $${'4321', '22', 'Piet', 'John'}$$;
INSERT 0 1
t=# with a as (select pk,unnest(a_key) k,unnest(a_val) v from so29)
select pk from a where k = 'name' and v = $$'John'$$;
 pk
----
  1
(1 row)
```